# Condicional após calculo de Bhaskara

Tags: python

Estou tentando adicionar um `if` para mostrar a ordem dos números crescentes na fórmula de Bhaskara, entretanto ele mostra mensagem de erro caso a raiz seja negativa ou não existem raízes. Como posso ajustar?

```
import math

def delta(a,b,c):
        return b ** 2 - 4 * a * c

def main():
        a = float(input("digite o valor de a: "))
        b = float(input("digite o valor de b: "))
        c = float(input("digite o valor de c: "))
        imprime_raizes(a,b,c)

def imprime_raizes(a, b, c):
        d = delta(a, b, c)

        if d == 0:
            raiz1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d))/(2 * a)
            print("A única raiz da equação é: ", raiz1)

        else:
            if d < 0:
                print("A Equação não possui raízes reais")

            else:
                raiz1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d))/(2 * a)
                raiz2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d))/(2 * a)
                print("A primeira raiz é: ", raiz1)
                print("A segunda raiz é: ", raiz2)

            if raiz1 > raiz2:
                    print("ordem crescente:  ", raiz1, raiz2)
```

Comment: Já tentou verificar o valor de `d`? Ele é `float`, então não é recomendado fazer `d == 0`, pois pode haver erros de representação e o valor não ser realmente zero.

Comment: Aliás, o último `if` utiliza os valores de `raiz1` e `raiz2`, mas se a equação não possuir raízes, essas variáveis nunca serão definidas, o que pode ocasionar o erro citado. Acredito que faltou uma indentação nesse `if` para deixá-lo dentro do `else`.

Answer (score 2):

Uma função de grau `n` pode ser escrita como um produto de três fatores:

- uma constante `a` não nula
- um função de primeiro grau `(x - r_n)`
- uma função de grau `n-1`

[image: a vezes <code>(x - r_n)</code> vezes função de grau <code>n-1</code>]

Levando isso recursivamente, chegamos a conclusão que toda função de grau `n` é um produto de `n` equações de primeiro grau:

[image: função de grau <code>n</code> representada como produto de <code>n</code> funções de primeiro grau]

Para achar a raiz da função, precisamos igualá-la a zero. Como a função de grau `n` foi reescrita como um produto (e `a` por definição é não nulo), isso significa que pelo menos uma das funções de primeiro grau que compõe a função do `n`-ésimo grau precisa ser zero. E que valor é esse? É `r_i`. `r_i` representa a raiz de uma das funções.

Tome, por exemplo, `r_n`. Quando `x = r_n`, temos o seguinte:

```
F_n(x) = a * (x - r_n) * F_n-1(x)
F_n(r_n) = a * (r_n - r_n) * F_n-1(r_n) = a * (0) * F_n-1(r_n) ==>
F_n(r_n) = 0
```

Independente do valor de `F_n-1(r_n)`.

Dito, isso, algumas considerações:

- eu posso ter `r_i` e `r_j`, para `i != j`, com `r_i == r_j`; isso significa que a raiz apareceu múltiplas vezes na função, mas a função continua com `n` raízes
- eu posso ter raízes repetidas sim
- a verdade da decomposição daquela decomposição de uma função de grau `n` para uma função de grau `n-1` se aplica nas seguintes condições:

  1. os coeficientes de `F_n(x)` são coeficientes reais
  2. a raiz extraído é um número complexo (só lembrando que todo número real pertence ao conjunto dos complexos)

Dito isso, então eu sou um defensor de que você deveria apresentar duas raízes idênticas para a equação e classificá-las como `r_1` e `r_2`. Isso evita o [problema da comparação por zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255936/condicional-ap%c3%b3s-calculo-de-bhaskara#comment525114_255936) devidamente percebido pelo [@AndersonCarlosWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss).

Para apresentar suas raízes em ordem estritamente não-decrescente, você pode se aproveitar da definição de [`sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.sqrt): retornar a raiz quadrada do número. Por definição, a raiz quadrada de um número não negativo é um número positivo. Com isso, posso afirmar:

```
x + sqrt(y) >= x - sqrt(y)
```

E o caso de igualdade só acontece quando `y == 0`.

Assim, eu reescreveria seu código desse jeito:

```
import math

def delta(a,b,c):
        return b**2 - 4*a*c

def main():
        a = float(input("digite o valor de a: "))
        b = float(input("digite o valor de b: "))
        c = float(input("digite o valor de c: "))
        imprime_raizes(a,b,c)

def imprime_raizes(a, b, c):
        d = delta(a, b, c)
        if d < 0:
            print("A equação não possui raízes reais")
        else:
            raiz1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d))/(2 * a)
            raiz2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d))/(2 * a)
            print("A maior raiz é: ", raiz1)
            print("A menor raiz é: ", raiz2)
```